# Associate a project in eclipse to sonar shows only master branch

Tags: eclipse, maven, branch, sonarqube

I'm testing SonarQube with a multi module maven project. We have three different branches analysed by jenkins jobs (Post-build Actions with Branch option set to out branch names) and each branch is shown in SonarQube server.
But if I associate a project in eclipse it shows me only the master branch. I'm unable to select another branch. I've tried to add the sonar.branch parameter at different places (parent pom, project pom, project and workspace settings), but I'm not able to select another branch then master.
I don't find documentation or any entries here related to this behaviour. Can someone give me a tip, please?

Regards
kaltokri

Answer (score 0):

Branches are not very well covered by SonarQube for the moment, and so it is for SonarQube Eclipse unfortunately.

If you want to see the issues of a branch of your project, you have to change the project association (right-click on the project > Sonar > Change project association) and force it to point to the remote "branch" project that exist on the SonarQube server.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

But I try to do a manual project association (right-click on the project > Sonar > Change project association) and it shows me only the project of the master branch.

Comment: In the wizard, even if an associated is suggested by default by Eclipse, you can click on the table cells and start typing the name of the project corresponding to the branch: Eclipse will suggest you every available project that matches what you've typed.